# Meteor.js - how can I receive POST data from another web app?

Tags: meteor, http-post

I have a Meteor app that currently polls another app for updates.  I would like to stop the inefficient polling and have the other app just POST data to the meteor app when it's ready.  How can I receive POST data in my meteor app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in [webapp package](http://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html) to receive and respond HTTP requests on the server side. It works without any additional packages (such as iron router, flow router etc.).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Iron Router](http://atmospherejs.com/package/iron-router), you can setup a [server route](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#server-side-routing) to handle the request:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Router.map(function () {
    this.route('serverRoute', {
      where: 'server',
      path: '/server',
      action: function() {
        if (this.request.method === 'POST')
          this.response.end("handling post request");
      }
    });
  });
}
```